# Horizontal alignment of feynmp-graphs in equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, feynmp, feynmp-auto

I have a hard time aligning diagrams in equations where everything fits on the same line:

[image]

As you can see the + is not aligned with the external lines. Here is the code

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{standalone}
            
            
\usepackage[force]{feynmp-auto}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{} % for being able to read the produced file
            
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
    
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{fmffile}{psi-phi}
\begin{fmfgraph}(4,3)% units are now in cm
\fmfleft{i}
\fmfright{o}
\fmflabel{$\phi$}{i}
\fmf{fermion}{i,v}
\fmf{dashes}{v,v}
\fmf{fermion}{v,o}
\fmfdot{v}
\end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}
&\quad + \quad&
\begin{fmffile}{phi-psi}
\begin{fmfgraph}(4,3)% units are now in cm
\fmfleft{i}
\fmfright{o}
\fmflabel{$\phi$}{i}
\fmf{dashes}{i,v}
\fmf{fermion}{v,v}
\fmf{dashes}{v,o}
\fmfdot{v}
\end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}
\end{eqnarray}
        
\end{document}
```

I'm compiling with XelateX. Also, I am not interested in solutions that are based on `tikz-feynman`.

Comment: Please make the code as complete as necessary to a) compile and b) show your problem. Hardly anybody is going to do the guesswork about your document.

Comment: The is my first post in a long time. I have edited the code so it can be used right away. Hope this helps

Comment: As for my last edit: The OP accidentially edited their post by replacing the original code with that of another question. I was asked to undo this last edit by the OP.

Comment: You should use `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}` instead of `\documentclass{standalone}` for this MWE, because `standalone` does not provide the `eqnarray` environment as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To align two graphs I have used before `\parbox{40mm}` and after `\parbox{30mm}`. Here there is the result.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
            
            
\usepackage[force]{feynmp-auto}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{} % for being able to read the produced file
            
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
    
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{fmffile}{psi-phi}
\parbox{40mm}{\begin{fmfgraph}(4,3)% units are now in cm
\fmfleft{i}
\fmfright{o}
\fmflabel{$\phi$}{i}
\fmf{fermion}{i,v}
\fmf{dashes}{v,v}
\fmf{fermion}{v,o}
\fmfdot{v}
\end{fmfgraph}}
\end{fmffile}
&\quad + \quad&
\begin{fmffile}{phi-psi}
\parbox{30mm}{\begin{fmfgraph}(4,3)% units are now in cm
\fmfleft{i}
\fmfright{o}
\fmflabel{$\phi$}{i}
\fmf{dashes}{i,v}
\fmf{fermion}{v,v}
\fmf{dashes}{v,o}
\fmfdot{v}
\end{fmfgraph}}
\end{fmffile}
\end{eqnarray}    
\end{document}
```