# Different sizes printed for Feynman diagrams

Tags: xetex, diagrams, feynmp, feynmp-auto

When compiling the following:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{standalone}


\usepackage[force]{feynmp-auto}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{} % for being able to read the produced file

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{fmffile}{phi-phi}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(4,3)% units are now in cm
    %       \fmfpen{thick}
    \fmfleft{i}
    \fmfright{o}
    \fmflabel{$x$}{i}
    \fmflabel{$y$}{v}
    \fmflabel{$z$}{o}
    \fmf{plain}{i,v,v,o}
    \fmfdot{v}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{fmffile}{psi-psi}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(4,3)% units are now in cm
    %       \fmfpen{thick}
    \fmfleft{i}
    \fmfright{o}
    \fmflabel{$x$}{i}
    \fmflabel{$y$}{v}
    \fmflabel{$z$}{o}
    \fmf{dashes}{i,v,v,o}
    \fmfdot{v}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}
\end{equation*}
    
\end{document}
```

I get the output:

[image]

What is going wrong?

I'm compiling with XelateX. Also, I am not interested in solutions that are based on `tikz-feynman`.

Comment: Sorry, but your MWE does not compile for me. Maybe some packages are missing?

Comment: I accidentally updated the code in an older post of mine: [link]( https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/666632/horizontal-alignment-of-feynmp-graphs-in-equations ). Is it possible to undo this?

Comment: I rolled back your edits of the other post. Please check

Comment: Rewrite your MWE, this one doesn`t works...

Comment: Thanks! Should I update this code with all my packages now?

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a code snippet that is compilable and shows the problem you are facing. You don't need to put *all* the packages you use. Only put those which are necessary for compilation of this code snippet (see my answer how such a code snippet could look like).

Comment: Apart from the Feynman package, there isn't really another package (relevant to this problem). Thanks anyways, it seems this is going to take time.

Comment: @M91 You can't use `equation*` without loading e.g. the `amsmath` package. Also `standalone` will cause troubles because it does not have a fixed width. Please test your code before posting to make sure there aren't any errors in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you are really doing, since your MWE does not produce the output you show. Maybe what is going wrong is that somehow in your code the `\unitlength` is being reset or overwritten. The following compiles just fine with both pictures having the same size:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[force]{feynmp-auto}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{} % for being able to read the produced file

\begin{document}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{fmffile}{phi-phi}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(4,3)% units are now in cm
    %       \fmfpen{thick}
    \fmfleft{i}
    \fmfright{o}
    \fmflabel{$x$}{i}
    \fmflabel{$y$}{v}
    \fmflabel{$z$}{o}
    \fmf{plain}{i,v,v,o}
    \fmfdot{v}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{fmffile}{psi-psi}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(4,3)% units are now in cm
    %       \fmfpen{thick}
    \fmfleft{i}
    \fmfright{o}
    \fmflabel{$x$}{i}
    \fmflabel{$y$}{v}
    \fmflabel{$z$}{o}
    \fmf{dashes}{i,v,v,o}
    \fmfdot{v}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}
\end{equation*}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot to -shell-escape (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99475/how-to-invoke-latex-with-the-shell-escape-flag-in-texstudio-former-texmakerx). Thanks again